# boost::asio and recursive server calls

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

Does boost::asio handle the recursive server connections correctly?

I have a TCP/IP asynchronous server which connects to itself from within the async_read handler and seems to deadlock: the next async_accept is working but async_read blocks.

The server is based on the http asio example with a thread pool.

It implements a certain API that clients are using and may also delegate some of the functions to another server (acting like a proxy or a cloud node). The problem is that when another server is localhost (e.g. itself) the deadlock occurs somewhere inside asio libraries.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well I actually figured out there is a global SSL strand inside ASIO that causes the deadlock. It's quite unfortunate as I have to look for a workaround now.
As a matter of fact there is a patch that improves the situation but doesn't completely solve it: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3958

Answer (score 1):

I actually found out that the problem is with SSL sockets - the handshake function deadlocks when the server calls itself. Probably related to a strand inside the asio ssl code.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe you could submit your question to the ASIO users mailing list: https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/asio-users